# Enable/Install WSL within a Docker Windows container

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-container, docker-for-windows

I am wanting to enable and install the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) feature from within a Docker windowsservrecore container.
However, due to the fact that Docker containers are more like full-environment-processes than VMs,
and because WSL feature installation requires a 'system reboot'; this has proven troublesome.

I have seen solutions that other people have figured out for installing features that normally 'require reboot' in a Docker windows container.

- e.g. Active Directory support: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/containerstuff/2017/01/30/create-a-container-with-active-directory-support/
- e.g. Server Media Foundation:
  https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-server-media-foundation-in-a-docker-container/23587

So I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts or has managed something similar for getting WSL to install in a Docker windows container?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WSL requires kernel mode driver called LxCore.sys and Lxss.sys. So it may not possible in docker.